# How can I apply a powerpoint macro to the slide I am currently viewing?

Tags: vb.net, macros, powerpoint

I am working in VB in powerpoint and I am trying to write a simple macro that resizes and centers any image only on the slide that I am currently editing.  I have successfully written code that sizes and centers the image but it only works on the first slide in my presentation, even if I am currently viewing and editing a different slide.  How can I apply the code to the slide I am viewing?

The code is the following:

```
Dim shp As Shape
Dim sld as Slide

Dim x As Integer
Dim y As Integer

With ActivePresentation.PageSetup
x = .SlideWidth / 2
y = .SlideHeight / 2
End With


For Each sld In ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange
For Each shp In sld.Shapes

If shp.Type = msoPicture Then
shp.Height = y * 2 

shp.Width = x * 2

shp.Left = x - (shp.Width / 2)
shp.Top = y - (shp.Height / 2)
End If

Next
Next


End Sub
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: What does the rest of your code look like?

Comment: please put more code related to the query.

Comment: Thanks, I now posted the entirety of my script above

Answer (score 0):

Step through your code and see what happens after this line:

If shp.Type = msoPicture Then

Do the following lines execute after slide 1?  I'm guessing that you have shapes of type msoPlaceholder rather than msoPicture, so your sizing code never triggers.

Try this instead:

```
Dim shp As Shape
Dim sld As Slide

Dim x As Integer
Dim y As Integer

With ActivePresentation.PageSetup
x = .SlideWidth / 2
y = .SlideHeight / 2
End With


For Each sld In ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange
For Each shp In sld.Shapes

If shp.Type = msoPicture Then
shp.Height = y * 2

shp.Width = x * 2

shp.Left = x - (shp.Width / 2)
shp.Top = y - (shp.Height / 2)
End If

If shp.Type = msoPlaceholder Then
    If shp.PlaceholderFormat.ContainedType = msoPicture Then
        shp.Height = y * 2
        shp.Width = x * 2
        shp.Left = x - (shp.Width / 2)
        shp.Top = y - (shp.Height / 2)
    End If
End If

Next
Next
```